How can JMeter be used to test the performance of Android/iOS native apps?
I found resources for testing mobile web by setting up a network and SSL certificate. How can this be done for native apps using JMeter?

What performance risks are you looking for to investigate?


For iOS you will need to enable full trust for JMeter's certificate

For Android you will additionally need to amend your applications network security settings like:

In the application tag of your app manifest add the next line:
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"


Create network_security_config.xml file under your application resources directory and put the following code there:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>


Build your application in debug mode

Replace the original .apk on the device with the newly built one


More information: Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording and Configuring an Android device to work with Burp Suite


